# How to configure eth1 to be a failsafe for eth0?

Tags: networking, network-bonding

I need to configure `eth1` to be a failsafe interface for `eth0`. When `eth0` is down `eth1` goes up and when `eth0` is up `eth1` goes down. I need to do this from `/etc/network/interfaces`.